# Implementing a first-in-first-out fixed-length array controller in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to implement a fixed-length array controller in Ember.js, and have it so that it removes the first item when the list exceeds its capacity. My attempt is below, but it is failing with an error.

**EDIT**: I now have a simple jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/39/

I have a view that is associated with the array controller. I believe that the error is due to the view. When I remove it the error goes away and I am able to pop out the first object. (NB: The view worked fine until I tried implementing the FIFO feature.)

I have also tried putting the contents of the popFirst function in a runloop (Ember.run(...)).

Does anyone know how I could implement this fifo array and have the view still work?

```js
MyApp.fifoController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [],
  popFirst: (function() {
    if (this.get('length') >= 3) {
      return this.removeObject(this.get('firstObject'));
    }
  }).observes('length')
});

<div id="fifo-pool">
  {{#each MyApp.fifoController}}
    {{#view MyApp.ItemView contentBinding="this"}}{{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</div>


Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_insertElementLater' of undefined genigames/vendor/ember:16704
DOMManager.after genigames/vendor/ember:16704
Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend._scheduleInsertion genigames/vendor/ember:14708
Ember.ContainerView.states.hasElement.childViewsDidChange genigames/vendor/ember:14765
Ember.View.Ember.Object.extend.invokeForState genigames/vendor/ember:12902
Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend.childViewsDidChange genigames/vendor/ember:14687
...
```

**EDIT**: I now have a simple jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/39/

Comment: Could you post the code of the App.ItemView please ? Or even better a Jsfiddle ?

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem but see if using a collection instead of each works

`{{#collection elementId="fifo-pool" contentBinding="MyApp.fifoController" itemViewClass="MyApp.ItemView"}}`

Comment: I have edited the question above to include the link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/38/

Comment: @Bradley Priest: Replacing the each with your code (everything but the initial hash -- isn't that just if you want to include something in the view?) results in the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this wrong. You are observing length, adding an item, removing and item, and still observing length. Instead you should check if you need to remove before you even add the item. Ember has a really nice mixin system, so you can override the pushObject function, check for removal, and then call `_super` to add. See this example:

```
MyApp.fifoController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    pushObject: function(object) {
        if (this.get('length') >= 4) {
            this.removeObject(this.get('firstObject'));
        }
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MSKxG/

Comment: So this is very good so long as I'm using pushObject, and I could probably structure the app so that pushObject is always called, but it seems to me that this is not as general a solution as something that either observes 'length' or is otherwise notified when an object is (trying to be) added.